# Creating unique Barcode generator SQL query

Tags: sql, sapb1

I'm trying to create a query to generate unique barcode number for each item, but yet I haven't come up with the logic behind it. (SAP B1)

At this moment there are approximately 500 items in database without barcode. This query

1. Should automatically assign barcodes to each existing item
2. Should have a logic to generate new barcode number when I'm creating new.

I thought that using Item `ROW_NUM()` function and `RIGHT` would be a good choice:

Query will sort list by (with `ORDER BY`) Item creation time, get row number and convert it to barcode number with `RIGHT` function

For Example:

```
select right('000000000000' + cast(Row_Number as varchar(12)), 12)
```

Barcode for fist item (first in list) will be`000000000001`
for second `000000000002` etc.

Is it possible?

p.s. Presumably, this would be not useful for non-existent items. In Item creation process, row number will not be assigned yet.

Comment: Ideally you should be providing example data and expected results so we have a beter understanding..  See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I think `select CASE WHEN barcode IS NULL THEN right('000000000000' + cast(Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY Item_Creation_Time) as varchar(12)), 12)` ELSE barcode END as barcode...` would seem reasonable to me.

Comment: "Should automatically assign barcodes to each existing item" - unless the barcode field is a UDF, you shouldn't be setting fields directly with SQL. It's a great way to void your warranty.